# ggplot2 using facet_grid to generate Pie charts for each row

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to generate pie charts for this data.frame where each row represents a unique identifier for a site, the errors count for the fields and the, number of fields. How best would I structure the the ggplot command to produce a pie chart with errors being a fraction of the the fields for each site?
Currently, my code looks like the following:

```
ggplot(error_indicator,aes(x = Fields,y=Errors)) 
+ facet_grid(~Hospital) 
+ geom_bar(width = 1,stat="identity", position="fill") 
+ coord_polar(theta="y")
```

The dataframe looks like the following:

[image]

But the result from my ggplot code looks like the following:

[image]

How do I get the pie charts to show errors as ratios of the fields for each hospital and each hospital using its own row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, pie charts is not the best way to show your data!

But anyway here is one solution. Most important part here is `scale_y_continuous()` to set limits from 0 to 1 and then convert them to percents using `percent_format()` from library `scales`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(df,aes(x=1,y=Errors/Fields))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  facet_grid(~Hospital)+
  coord_polar(theta="y")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(),limits=c(0,1),
              breaks=c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1))+
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

Comment: Which graphs would you prefer that I use and how would I implement it in a similar faceted way? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps a matter of taste, but I would find easier to compare the error rate at different hospitals using a non-faceted plot: `ggplot(df, aes(x = Hospital, y = Errors/Fields)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(),limits = c(0, 1),
                     breaks=c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1))`. And +1 to @Didzis Elferts for a nice answer where I learned about the `percent_format`.

Comment: I keep getting the error Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale using my dataset. I don't understand why I keep getting this error.

Comment: Include your data in the question using function dput(df)